# creating xls file in labview using read/write, the file you are trying to open xls is in a different format than specified by the extension

Tags: excel, labview

I tried to create an xls file in labview 2010 as shown below:
[image]

I get something like below in this excel file:

```
0.13    0.01    99
0.51    0.02    99
13.97   0.55    8.81
23.11   0.91    12.04
36.7    1.45    8.74
50.42   1.99    8.67
```

However, when I open excel I get the warning that:

> "the file you are trying to open xls is in a different format than
>   specified by the extension"

when I change the file to a .csv, I no longer get this error. But I need excel to open it in the xls format without the warning. Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LabVIEW cannot directly write to an XLS format file.

- You can write a CSV and open it in Excel (Excel will open a CSV file with a .xls extension, as you are seeing).
- On Windows you can use the Report Generation Toolkit or one of the Excel automation interfaces (.NET/ActiveX) to tell Excel to write an XLS file with the values that you specify programatically.  This requires that Excel be installed on the local machine.
- In LabVIEW 2013 you can use the "Write to Measurement File Express VI" to write directly to XLS**X** files without having Excel installed.
- There may be a non-NI support library or command line tool you could call but I'm not aware of one.

This document explains a little more:
http://www.ni.com/newsletter/51339/en/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to write to .xls (not .xslx) format directly from LabVIEW there is a [third party toolkit available from NI](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/212056), but it costs extra.

Alternatively if you can use Python (for example) you could write a short Python script to convert a csv file to xls using the [xlwt package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt), and call this from LabVIEW using System Exec. I expect there are similar packages available in other scripting languages.